# Cannot Reindex Data's In Magento Admin & Shell

Tags: php, shell, magento, reindex

I have 70k products in my magento site.
I need to reindex the product data's in admin panel.
When i have tried to reindex the data's in Magento Admin panel it give below error.

```
Cannot Initialize the Indexer Process
```

So i have planned to reindex the data's using Shell access,
it show me the below error message.

I have rooted inside the shell folder & executed this command

```
php -f indexer.php reindexall
```

When i execute above command, it gives the below error message.

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'dbModel read resource does not implement Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract' in /home/demo/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php:187
Stack trace:
#0 /home/demo/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/Db/Collection/Abstract.php(134): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->setConnection(false)
#1 /home/demo/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Db_Collection_Abstract->__construct(Array)
#2 /home/demo/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getModelInstance('index_resource/...', Array)
#3 /home/demo/public_html/magento/app/Mage.php(490): Mage_Core_Model_Config->getResourceModelInstance('index/process_c...', Array)
#4 /home/demo/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Index/Model/Indexer.php(67): Mage::getResourceModel('index/process_c...')
#5 /home/demo/public_html/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php(1348): Mage_Index_Model_Indexer-> in /home/demo/public_html/magento/lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php on line 187
```

Can anyone point out me what was the issues?

THanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a permission problem. `chmod -R 777 var/*` should solve it. Try removing `var/cache/*` first.

Comment: i have deleted the files in var/cache folder then reindex the data's one by one it stuck to showing "processing" in orange color bg..no luck

Comment: Did you still get this error ? Have you tried setting the permissions of var/* to 777 ?

Comment: yes, i have 777 file permission under var folder.Still i get the error and now showing "Processing" in orange color.

Comment: There is a detailed answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362601/dbmodel-read-resource-does-not-implement-zend-db-adapter-abstract-in-magento-ver

Comment: 777 permissions is an insecure configuration.

Answer (score 1):

It may be a caching problem. If you have enabled APC, you should probably disable it, restart Apache and try re-indexing again.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are missing a local.xml file.